# Fiware Cepheus: can we persist data in the gateway using Cepheus?

Tags: fiware

Can we use Cepheus to persist data locally on the gateway?

Use case: connection to the remote Orion server was lost for some time, we store the events locally and then when the connection get back we send them to the remote server.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiware-Cepheus](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/fiware-cepheus) does not currently (v0.1.5) buffers nor persists any data on the gateway.
Data that could not be forwarded to a remote broker due to a connection issue is lost.

But this feature could be added, any contribution is welcomed !

EDIT: I added an issue to track this feature [here](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/fiware-cepheus/issues/49)

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
We are interested in adding persistence to Cepheus. 
We are working in a project that needs this feature and we are ready to contribute! Please telt me how to?